# Run Java computation engine from .Net

Tags: java, vb.net, interop

I have a scenario where we have written a domain specific computation engine in Java as a part of a heavy-weight Swing application.  So far so good.

Emerging requirements now have us integrating part of this capability, namely the computation engine and its output, with another legacy product which is written as a web application in VB.NET.  Is there a way to:

1. Have the .NET web application call the Java compute engine and iterate over its output
2. Also have the ability to call the same Java compute engine from a Java applet for output presentation similar to the original Swing application (this shouldn't be hard unless the underlying assumption about the compute engine being Java based changes)
3. Have the compute engine remain as one code base so any changes for one application are also automatically reflected in the other

I've looked at the other questions about calling Java code from .NET languages but have not seen this dual use scenario before and was wondering if there was a suggested best practice.

Comment: What do you mean by `a dual-use scenario`? You mean calling the engine from an Applet as well as a .NET app?

Comment: Precisely.  I want to access the compute engine from Java code as well as .NET code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What comes to mind would be to wrap your Java engine behind a web end point. This endpoint, such as a REST web service, or something similar will allow other applications to communicate with your Java engine without them caring how is the engine itself implemented.

This would also allow you to make changes on the Java engine and them becoming instantly available to the other applications, since the logic will be in one place.

Comment: Great idea. The web service would then be available to any platform or language. That's the beauty of web services. It's all done over HTTP (usually) and so can be consumed by any system that can "talk" HTTP. Your security becomes easy too. If you only want the service to run locally and not be exposed to the internet you could simply set it up to only allow connections from the localhost.

Comment: @PaulSasik: There could still be some problem (serialization of custom types comes to mind) but once that you overcome that, I think that most of the work should be done.

Comment: if serialization of data becomes a problem then it would have to be self-inflicted. Why would the OP not use XML or JSON to pass data as part of the web service calls?

Comment: @PaulSasik: Yeah I agree but you never know, some times you need to fix problems left behind by those before you.